# Por que no funciona el programa, al cambiar el condicional?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un código, que evita mostrar el alert cuando el input este en focus:

```js
var focused = false;
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{ 
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
for(var input of inputs){
  input.addEventListener("focus",()=>{
  focused = true;
  });
}
  redirect(); 
});

function redirect(){
  window.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if((e.key === "y" || e.key == "Y") && !focused) alert("Ir a youtube?");
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="Escribime aqui"/>
</body>
</html>
```

***El código funciona de buena manera, el problema es que al modificar la funcion redirect() y dejando la variable focused en un solo condicional, el código no funciona, así:***

```js
var focused = false;
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{ 
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
for(var input of inputs){
  input.addEventListener("focus",()=>{
  focused = true;
  });
}
  redirect(); 
});

function redirect(){
  if(!focused){
  window.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if(e.key === "y" || e.key == "Y") alert("Ir a youtube?");
  });
  }  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="Escribime aqui"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hacemos un poco de console log para seguir el flujo del programa y detectar lo que pasa.

```js
var focused = false;
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
console.log('1 Entramos en el load y el valor de focused es : ', focused);
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

for(var input of inputs){
  input.addEventListener("focus",()=>{
  console.log('5 Hacemos focus en un input siendo el valor de focused: ', focused);
  focused = true;
  console.log('y lo cambiamos a:', focused);
  });
}

  console.log('2 vamos a llamar a redirect siendo el valor de focused:  ', focused);
  redirect(); 
});

function redirect(){
  console.log('3 Valor de focused: ', focused);
  if(!focused){
    console.log('4 el evento keyup se ha añadido siendo focused: ', focused);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
      console.log('6 entrando en el evento keyup focused es:', focused);
      if(e.key === "y" || e.key == "Y") alert("Ir a youtube?");
    });
  } else {
    console.log('4 el evento keyup no se ha añadido ya que focused es:', focused);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="Escribime aqui"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Si ahora lo aplicamos al primer código:

```js
var focused = false;
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{ 
  console.log('1 Entramos en el load y el valor de focused es : ', focused);
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
  for(var input of inputs){
    input.addEventListener("focus",()=>{
      console.log('3 el valor de focused antes de comprobarlo es:  ', focused);
      focused = true;
      console.log('y lo cambiamos a :  ', focused);
    });
  }
  console.log('2 vamos a llamar a redirect siendo el valor de focused:  ', focused);
  redirect(); 
});

function redirect(){
  window.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    console.log('4 el valor de focused antes de comprobarlo es:  ', focused);
    if((e.key === "y" || e.key == "Y") && !focused) alert("Ir a youtube?");
    console.log('5 y por eso nunca se ejecuta nuestro alert');
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="Escribime aqui"/>
</body>
</html>
```

En su segundo código solo pregunta el estado del **focused**  una vez, exactamente para añadir el evento, pero nunca dentro de su **callback**, claramente siempre es true y añade el evento.

Sin embargo es normal que no funcione en su primer código porque se ejecuta el **callback** del **focus** antes que el del **keyUp** invalidando la ejecución del **alert**.

En mi humilde opinión es un poco tonto preguntar si un input tiene focus activado en una callback de keyUp. Puesto que el primero implica el segundo, pero a gustos colores. :)